# Proper encapsulation with class relations when creating objects

Tags: c++, oop

I’m writing for practice a C++ wrapper over libusb. I want my API to fully hide the implementation of the underlying lib: the user should not even know I’m actually using libusb. So I created two classes: `Context` and `Device`. A `Device` is created from a `Context` using the `open` method.

So:

```
//--- context.hpp -------------------
class Context final
{
public:
  Context();
  ~Context();

  std::unique_ptr<Device> open(uint16_t vid, uint16_t pid);

private:
  struct Impl;
  std::unique_ptr<Impl> impl;
};

//--- context.cpp -------------------
struct Context::Impl
{
  libusb_context* ctx;
};

Context::Context()
  : impl(std::make_unique<Impl>())
{ /* ... */ }

//--- device.hpp -------------------
class Device final
{
public:
  Device();
  ~Device();

private:
  struct Impl;
  std::unique_ptr<Impl> _impl;
};

//--- device.cpp -------------------
struct Device::Impl
{
  libusb_device_handle* handle;
}

Device::Device()
  : _impl(std::make_unique<Impl>())
{}
```

Now the question is: how do I implement the `open` method? I need to call `libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid` in the implementation which will take the `libusb_context*` of my `Context::Impl` and store the handle in `Device::Impl`. Here are options I thought:

1. I create a constructor of `Device` taking a pointer to `Context`, but the ctor of `Device` does not have access to the `libusb_context*` pointer to call the function;
2. I follow point number one and put the `Context::Impl` in a header and make `Device` a friend of `Context`: this sounds ugly though;
3. I create a constructor of `Device` that takes a `libusb_context*` pointer: but I’d be breaking the encapsulation, the user should’nt see the libusb details;
4. I add a `native_handle` method to `Context` so I can do number one and get the implementation pointer but causing the same problem as number three.
5. I make the function call in `open` but how do I initialize my `Device` with the `libusb_device_handle*` I get? I can’t have a ctor of `Device` taking such a pointer, breaking the encapsulation.

Comment: Does the user need to see a *context* object at all? Could that just be a hidden implementation detail of `Device`? I'm not familiar with `libusb` but often context type objects are a `C` handle to maintain instance information. In `C++` that same job is often done internal to the class - the class object **is** its own handle.

Comment: @Galik There can be multiple devices per context, and multiple contexts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `friend`-based solution is in fact the cleanest, it's what `friend` was designed for.

```
// device.hpp
class Device final
{
public:
  ~Device();

private:
  Device();
  struct Impl;
  std::unique_ptr<Impl> impl;
  friend class Context;
};

// device.cpp
struct Device::Impl
{
  libusb_device_handle* handle;
  Impl() : handle(nullptr) {}
}

Device::Device() : impl(new Device::Impl()) {}

std::unique_ptr<Device> Context::open(uint16_t vid, uint16_t pid) {
  std::unique_ptr<Device> result(new Device());
  result->impl->handle = libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid(vid, pid);
  return result;
}
```

Note that you can actually return `Device` rather than `std::unique_ptr<Device>` and treat all your bindings as value objects to avoid the extra level of indirection.

EDIT: another option is to use a void pointer. This removes the friend declaration at the expense of introducing a potentially unsafe cast.

```
// device.hpp
class Device final
{
public:
  ~Device();

private:
  Device(void *handle);
  struct Impl;
  std::unique_ptr<Impl> impl;
};

// device.cpp
struct Device::Impl
{
  libusb_device_handle* handle;
  Impl(void *handle)
    : handle(static_cast<libusb_device_handle*>(handle)) {}
}

Device::Device(void *handle)
  : impl(new Device::Impl(handle)) {}

std::unique_ptr<Device> Context::open(uint16_t vid, uint16_t pid) {
  void *handle = libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid(vid, pid);
  std::unique_ptr<Device> result(new Device(handle));
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Despite it already uses friendship, wouldn't it still be better to `return std::unique_ptr<Device>(new Device(libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid(vid, pid)));`?

Comment: Initializing attributes of `Device` inside the `Context` class feels wrong, isn't it? Shouldn't it be done by a `Device` ctor taking the `Context` as parameter and make the function call? The friendship would be the other way around: `Device` a friend of `Context`. Also, if I use objects instead of pointers, how can I pass the object to a function without copying it (wouldn't make sense) and without invalidating the caller argument by moving it? Maybe pass a reference?

Comment: If you don't want to directly initialize the attribute, you can pass the libusb handle to the constructor using a void pointer. I updated the answer.

Comment: Setting up the friendship the other way around would be rather confusing. The above implementation of `open()` follows a pattern known as a factory method: you use a method on an object to create some other object related to it. Still, if you want to do it the other way, you can use `const Context &` as the parameter type - this will pass an object without copying it.